# Questions about `〜はる` 敬語

Tags: verbs, etymology, politeness, keigo

One thing I've never fully gotten a grasp on is the `〜はる` form of "`敬語`", and I have some questions about it.

1. Is it official `敬語` recognized by the `文部省`, or is it just more of a regionally accepted politeness?

   - What regions even use this form commonly?
2. What is its politeness level, and how does it compare/fit it with `丁寧語・尊敬語・謙譲語`?

   - I was once stopped in Osaka by the police (because my bicycle was *clearly* stolen </sarcasm>) and they used it toward me - `どこで買わはりました？`
3. Which `はる` is this, and how did it evolve to this usage of politeness?

Apologies if this is too many questions for one topic.

Comment: I was stopped by the police in Leicester, too... hehehe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's Kansai dialect. I don't think it's official 敬語 recognized by 文科省.
2. It's 尊敬語.

   > 食べはる ≒ 食べられる, 召し上がる
   >   [来]{き}はる ≒ [来]{こ}られる, いらっしゃる
   >   先生が来はった。≒ 先生が来られた, 先生がいらっしゃった

   I think ~~はる sounds less polite/formal than the standard 尊敬語.
3. I think it comes from なさる (--> なはる --> はる ?)

Comment: 1. 2. 3. にならない・・・1. 2. 1. になるんですけど・・・(T_T)

Comment: Why is `来はる` キ instead of コ?  構成は　否定形の語幹＋はる　なんじゃない？

Comment: @istrasci おおっ！「[来]{こ}はる」「[来]{こ}はらへん」じゃなくて「[来]{き}はる」「[来]{き}はらへん」ですね。なんでだろう！？他のと違うんだぁ・・・初めて知りましたwww

Comment: @itrasci, according to http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AF%E3%82%8B#.E5.8A.A9.E5.8B.95.E8.A9.9E:.E3.81.AF.E3.82.8B, it's regional whether it attaches to 未然形 or 連用形. But apparently 来る is always きはる, and 通る is always 通らはる, so the grammar seems a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: @Chocolate 感覚的な話で申し訳ないのですが、「来はる」って、もうひとつ「敬語的な響き」がしませんね。やはり、「来る」という、非敬語的な動詞が元になっているからだと思いますが、関西には「ござる」または「いらっしゃる」をベースとした敬語の動詞は存在しますか。ちなみに、名古屋弁には「ござらした」とか「ござりゃーた」という言葉があります。「いらっしゃった」という意味ですが、これの関西版があれば知りたいと思います。ヨロ

Comment: @TokyoNagoya 「来た」という意味での「いらっしゃった」には「来はった」、「居た」という意味での「いらっしゃった」には「いはった」を使うと思います。「ござ(ら/る)～」で始まるものはなさそうです。特に京都では「～はる/～はった」はあまり敬語として意識しないで使うので、本当に敬語が必要な場面では標準語の敬語を使います。